# How do i make my dupicate function finish before sheet function activates

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

so i have a function duplicate sheet, but i also have another function that says getheetname. my getsheetname function is something that i have written down in A1, but the duplicatesheet function gets called when i press a draawing. what happens is that when i duplicate my sheet, the name of the sheet written in cell A1 is copy of template instead of the name that i give when calling the duplicatesheet function. how can i make sure that it writes down the name that i give up in the ui?

```
var nameofSheet; // create global variable, to use in multiple functions, and set a default name to it

function duplicateSheet() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Template");

  var response = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Nieuwe sheet", "Wat moet de Titel van de nieuwe sheet worden?", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  if (response.getSelectedButton() == SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK && response.getResponseText() == "") {
    // If the response is empty, call the function recursively
    duplicateSheet();
  } else if (response.getSelectedButton() == SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK && response.getResponseText() != "") {
    // If the name is given, get the name of the sheet and log it
    nameofSheet = response.getResponseText();
    console.log("Dit is de sheetnaam: " + nameofSheet);

    // Create a new sheet and set its name
    var newSheet = sheet.copyTo(sheet.getParent()).setName(nameofSheet);
    
    // Copy values and formats
    sheet.getDataRange().copyTo(newSheet.getRange(1, 1));
    
  // Get merged cell ranges from the original sheet
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    var range = sheet.getRange("A1:F50");
    var mergedRanges = range.getMergedRanges();

    // Copy and log merged cells
    for (var i = 0; i < mergedRanges.length; i++) {
      var mergedRange = mergedRanges[i];
      var newMergedRange = newSheet.getRange(
        mergedRange.getRow(),
        mergedRange.getColumn(),
        mergedRange.getNumRows(),
        mergedRange.getNumColumns()
      );
      newMergedRange.merge();
      console.log(mergedRanges[i].getA1Notation());
      console.log(mergedRanges[i].getDisplayValue());
    }
  } else {
    throw("Je hebt het maken van een nieuwe sheet geannuleerd");
  }
}

/**
 * Haalt de naam van de sheet op
 * 
 * @customfunction
 */
function getSheetName() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  console.log("sheet name: " + sheet.getName())
  return sheet.getName();
```

i have tried everything and a lot of different ways to call the function with delays etc., but noting works.

Comment: Your function `getSheetName` is an installed on change trigger?

Comment: Hey user20856259, any luck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can i make sure that it writes down the name that i give up in the ui?

This line:

```
sheet.getDataRange().copyTo(newSheet.getRange(1, 1));
```

Should be:

```
sheet.getDataRange().copyTo(newSheet.getDataRange())
```

Or at the very least:

```
newSheet.getRange("A1").setValue(nameofSheet)
```

Comment: @user20856259 Great! Please consider selecting the checkmark to mark this is answered.

Comment: it still doesnt work immediately, however if i reload the page it will get the correct value

Comment: @user20856259 Maybe try adding `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` after you're finished your operations